# Error: "ReferenceError: promise is not defined" adding promise to my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I have 3 web service calls being made from Node.js.  2 are ReST, 1 is SOAP.  All are wrapped in Promises.

I've gotten my ReST requests to return the promises correctly and these are accessible in the Promise.all block but when I add my SOAP request, I get a message saying Promise is not defined.

I'm using node v8.2.1.  I've tried request and request-promise but the same thing happens.  My code looks like this - anything I'm obviously doing wrong?

```
const locationRequest = require('request');
var soapPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    locationRequest(options1, function(error, response, output) {
        if (error) {
            console.info("soap error: " + error);
            reject(error);
        }
        else {
            console.info("soap success: " + response);
            resolve(response);
        }
    });
    return promise;
});

Promise.all([restPromise, photoPromise, soapPromise]) //addition of soapPromise causes the issue
    .then(function([restResult, photoResult, soapResult]) {
        //respond to client
        console.info("Resource: " + restResult.name);
        console.info("Photo Path: " + photoResult);
        console.info("Soap: " + soapResult);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.info("promise all error: " + error);
        res.send('done');
        //catch an error generated from either request
    })
```

Adding the `soapPromise` stuff gives me:

> ReferenceError: promise is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `return promise;` line. You're not expected to return anything out of the `Promise` executor (the callback you give `new Promise`), and it doesn't create a `promise` variable. So `promise` is an undefined identifier at that point, hence the `ReferenceError`.